# displaying an array of structures

Tags: c++

I'm working on this project:

> We want to convert these to a dynamic array of structures with an
>   additional exam average field.
>
> Your tasks are:
>
> 1. define a structure for student grade records
> 2. declare a dynamic array of structures
> 3. populate the structures from the parallel arrays
> 4. define a function to compute the average for a student and populate average field
> 5. define a function to display name and average for a.
>
> demonstrate your functions and program by printing the name and
>   average for each student.

Can someone help with my code

My code reads an error for this line:

```
cout << "Average:" << avg[i] << endl;
```

My code is:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;

//Structure named studentrecord
struct StudentRecord
{
    string name;
    int test_scores[4];
    double avg;

    double computeAvg();                //member function to compute the average of test scores for a student
    void showRecord();              //member function to display a student record
};

int main()
{
    //set the parallel arrays of names and scores.

    string name[] = {"A.Adelaide", "B.Bali","C.Cebu", "D.Dauphin","E.Ellis"};

    int test_scores[][5] = { { 98,87,93,88},
                             { 78,86,82,91},
                             { 66,71,85,94},
                             { 72,63,77,69},
                             { 91,83,76,60} };

    StudentRecord *ptr = new StudentRecord[5];      //Dynamically allocate an array of structures

    //using the for loop to run the data through structure from the parallel arrays
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)//rows
    {
        ptr[i].name = name[i];
        for (int  j = 0; j < 5; j++)//columns
        {
            ptr[i].test_scores[j] = test_scores[i][j];
        }
    }

    double computeAvg();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        ptr[i].computeAvg();
    }

    void  showRecord();
    for (int i = 0; i <5 ; i++)
    {
        ptr[i].showRecord();
    }

    delete[] ptr;
    return 0;
}

double StudentRecord :: computeAvg()
{
    double total=0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        total += test_scores[i];
    }
    avg= (total / 4);
    return avg;
}

void StudentRecord::showRecord ()
{
    cout << fixed << showpoint<< setprecision(2);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << "Name:" << name[i] << endl;
        cout << "Average:" << avg[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Build output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Lab2.2, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Lab.cpp 1>Lab2.2.vcxproj -> E:\COSC 1437\Labs\Lab2.2\Debug\Lab2.2.exe
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: `avg` is not an array, you cannot use `[]` operator on it. And you probably don't want to print one letter of name each time either.

Comment: showRecord should probably look a little more like `cout << "Name: " name << endl; cout << "Average:" << avg << endl; for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(test_scores)/sizeof(test_scores[0]); ++i) cout << "Score" << i << ": " << test_scores[i] << endl;`

Comment: Is there no error message?

Comment: @user nope..@yksisarvinen thanks im trying

Comment: @user2079303 My psychic powers tell me the error message is something like `no operator [] defined for type double`.

Comment: @Lizan if there is no error message, then how do you know that there is an error?

Comment: @george she wants the name and avg

Comment: As noticed by George, you don't want to print `name` or `avg` in a loop. You should only print them once. Loop would only be useful for printing `test_scores`, but I think it's not necessary in your task.

Comment: Btw. I'm afraid you will get wrong results for `avg`. You have 5 elements but `avg= (total / 4);`. This is syntactically correct but mathematically wrong.

Comment: 1>------ Build started: Project: Lab2.2, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Lab.cpp
1>Lab2.2.vcxproj -> E:\COSC 1437\Labs\Lab2.2\Debug\Lab2.2.exe
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: it builds but the output is wild. it displays chars as the name, and runs through the same array of one student 4 times

Comment: You array in `main` has size 4x5, but you iterate over it as if it was 5x5. Same problem is in `StudentRecord::computeAvg()`

Comment: As me and George said, you don't want to use any loop in `showRecord`. Just print the name and avg, no loops involved.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I tried changing it and the fifth students' avg was an address. so i left it a is with 5x5 and it worked.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen and I fixed the loop as you said, and it compiled :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Some comments:

- Your StudentRecord has an array of size 4 to hold test results, and the scores are 5 rows with 4 scores each.
  However, for each student, you read 5 values from an array that only holds 4, and you write 5 values into an array that only holds 4.  Both of these are serious memory-corrupting errors. Look at your loop over the columns.
- avg[i] doesn't makes sense, because avg is just a single integer.
- stylistically, you repeat the number 5 several places.  It's best to use a named constant so it is consistent and documents what it means.
- also, ideally, your code wouldn't know how large the array given to you is.  You should write code to discover the size and adjust its work regardless of the size.  This means, instead of fixed size arrays, use dynamic, adjusting containers like a vector.  Raw arrays are discouraged these days in favor of vectors and other standard library containers because they do not "lose" information by decaying to a raw pointer, etc.  Consider using vectors (if assignment doesn't prohibit it).  Once an array decays, there is no way to extract the size of it.